# MYSQL query where per row with count

Tags: mysql

I have tried this and not reach and then i am asking my question

What i want

1. I want to search a name using mysql distinct like method

`Select name as name1 from table where name like '%name%' limit 100`

2. Then total 10 row comes with 10 names
3. Now i want to display only names which also contain more than 10 records if we search them like as following

`Select name as name1 from table where name like '%name%' and (select name from table where count(name)>10) limit 100`

I means i want a nested mysql query in which i want to display records only which should contain records more than per row.

if means if first 2 records are

gaurav jain
sumit singh

then gaurav jain only display if i put a select query to count nuber of gaurav jain where total gaurav jain records are more than 10

So i want this with each row . display row only where the row name is also more than 10 in table

I hope all is clear
3.

Comment: `I have tried this`. I dont see anything. Show what have you tried.?

Comment: i tried different queries in mysql but all failed so i ask here

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT name AS name1 FROM table WHERE name LIKE'%name%' AND (SELECT COUNT(name) FROM table WHERE name LIKE '%name%')>10 LIMIT 100
```

Comment: Hello Thanks for reply. this is not working. i am giving you my query. can you please check. what i am doing. i am trying to select first 2 words of names where each name should be more than 10 times in table. Following query i tried. SELECT DISTINCT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(name, ' ', 1)) AS name1 FROM table WHERE (SELECT COUNT(name1) as namec FROM table WHERE namec>10) and name REGEXP '^[a-zA-Z ]*$' ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 10

Comment: you have to work on this first: `WHERE (SELECT COUNT(name1) as namec FROM table WHERE namec>10)` . It's basically doing anything to your expression because the comparison is not happening on the main query

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what you are asking. This is a case where sample data and expected output would go a long ways in explaining the specification, much further than a SQL construct that "doesn't work" does.

From the rather disjointed description, it sounds as if you might be after the result returned from a query such as:

```
  SELECT t.name
    FROM mytable t
   WHERE t.name = '%foo%'
   GROUP BY t.name
  HAVING COUNT(1) >= 10
   LIMIT 20
```

That basically says: access rows from mytable and retrieve only the rows where the string 'foo' occurs somewhere in the name column.

Collapse all of the rows that have an identical value in the name column into a single row. And get a "count" of the number of rows that were collapsed in each group. If the number of rows (within the collapsed group) is at least ten, then return the name. Otherwise, don't return it. If there are more than twenty distinct names to return, return only the first twenty.

---

There are other query patterns that will return an equivalent result.

It is possible to use a correlated subquery, but that usually doesn't perform as well, and in some cases especially with large tables that don't have an appropriate index, performance can be abysmal.

```
  SELECT t.name
    FROM mytable t
   WHERE t.name LIKE '%foo%'
   GROUP BY t.name 
  HAVING ( SELECT COUNT(1)
             FROM mytable c
            WHERE c.name = t.name
         ) >= 10
   LIMIT 20
```